# Hadoop - producing multi column ouptut (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using Hadoop to apply map reduce in my MongoDB database.
I can able to execute the sample in [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-hadoop/).

Right now I can able to get only key, value pair in output collection after map reduce job was executed. I wonder if it is possible to save multiple columns in a map reduce output collection?
or embedded document in value column?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - use BSONWritable as your reducer output class, and create a BSONWritable object with as many columns as you need.

See example here:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/examples/treasury_yield/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/examples/treasury/TreasuryYieldReducer.java

Comment: Thanks for the hint.. I can able to get multi column output..
is it possible to output embedded document when using hadoop to apply map reduce in mongodb?